# Filter deep nested menu array if menu name includes in allowed menu string array

Tags: javascript, arrays, filter, menu

Hello i am trying to filter this menu to permitted menu
I have a menu structure as follows:

```
 const routes = [
    {
      path: '/dashboard',
      name: 'dashboard',
      children: [
        {
          path: '/style-guide',
          name: 'style_guide',
        },
      ],
    },
    {
      path: '/tables-management',
      name: 'tables_management',
      children: [
        {
          path: '/auxiliary',
          name: 'auxiliary',
          children: [
            {
              path: '/reporting-code',
              name: 'reporting_code',
            },
            {
              path: '/budget-levels',
              name: 'budget_levels',
            },
            {
              path: '/qr-codes',
              name: 'qr_codes',
            },
            {
              path: '/error-code',
              name: 'error_code',
            },
          ],
        },
    },
  ];
```

and this is the allowed routes

```
const pages= ["style_guide", "reporting_code", "qr_codes"]
```

and i want to filter the routes that includes in the pages array without hiding the parent route if have any children

so the results should show the dashboard route since style_guide is a visible child

i was trying to do so but its returning more than expected

```
const filter = (arr => {
    return arr.filter(obj => {
      if (obj.children && obj.children.length) {
        return filter(obj.children);
      }

      return !!(obj.name && pages.includes(obj.name));

    });
  });
```

what am i missing?
whats the best way to implement it
anyhow to it by spread operators?

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to reduce the array, because `filter` does not change the children array.

For an approach without mutating data, you need to create new objects.

```js
const
    getAllowed = (routes, pages) => routes.reduce((r, o) => {
        if (pages.includes(o.name)) {
            r.push(o);
        } else if (o.children) {
            let children = getAllowed(o.children, pages);
            if (children.length) r.push({ ...o, children });
        }
        return r;
    }, []),
    routes = [{ path: '/dashboard', name: 'dashboard', children: [{ path: '/style-guide', name: 'style_guide' }] }, { path: '/tables-management', name: 'tables_management', children: [{ path: '/auxiliary', name: 'auxiliary', children: [{ path: '/reporting-code', name: 'reporting_code' }, { path: '/budget-levels', name: 'budget_levels' }, { path: '/qr-codes', name: 'qr_codes' }, { path: '/error-code', name: 'error_code' }] }] }],
    pages = ["style_guide", "reporting_code", "qr_codes"],
    result = getAllowed(routes, pages);

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```